# Error while installing Laravel Spatie Permission

Tags: laravel, user-permissions, laravel-permission

While installing Laravel Spatie using the following command:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-permission
```

the following error in displayed:

[Click here to show the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnuH5.jpg)

How can I solve my problem to install Laravel Spatie ?

I tried to install the package via composer as follows:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-permission
```

The steps of installation in the following page

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/installation-laravel

And I can't expect how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As **the error says one thing to check for is any unexpected whitespace**, for example:
Verify it from `.env` file

`FIELD=some value`
vs
`FIELD="some value"`